# Unable to create custom object from spreadsheet

Tags: custom-object

While i was trying to create custom objects using spreadsheet (Object Manager -> Create Custom Objects from spreadsheet -> Takes you to https://object-creator.salesforce.com/), it always defaults to Google sheet automatically.

I googled it, but no remedy insight nor any relevant query was returned relating the erroneous behavior.

PS: I am trying this on Trailhead playground and also tried the same Partner Org, but same behavior.

Comment: You will get the 3 options like upload xls or.csv , google sheets  & office 365 or Drive

Comment: What format is your spreadsheet in anyway? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Here you can check step by step guide for Lightning object creator:
https://arrify.com/lightning-object-creator/

It should show three options.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.

It gives you those 3 options for 0.5 seconds and then the webpage redirects to another page where you can't do anything.

To fix this, I opened an incognito tab and logged in to SF from there, hoping that this would strip my Chrome browser of any extras (extensions, etc.) I have in my Chrome settings. It did the trick! Hoping the same works for you.

Comment: This same thing happened to me and this worked. I couldn't JUST open the object creator URL inside incognito. I had to open and log into my playground project URL in incognito and then go to the setup -> object manager -> Create schema from spreadsheet, log in with my playground user in incognito and then it didn't skip directly to google sheets on login.